# Probability: is it raining?

Tags: probability

You're about to get on a plane to Seattle. You want to know if you should bring an umbrella. You call 3 random friends of yours who live there and ask each independently if it's raining. Each of your friends has a 2/3 chance of telling you the truth and a 1/3 chance of messing with you by lying. All 3 friends tell you that "Yes" it is raining. What is the probability that it's actually raining in Seattle?

Attempt:

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the prior probability of it raining in Seattle.

Comment: Your attempt was to do nothing?

Comment: Ye... didn't have prior probability. This is actually an interview question

Comment: The real question here is "Why are you friends with these untrustworthy people?"

Comment: I was asked this question in a different company. I think it also helps to mention some numeric value for the general probability of rain in Seattle, say, some 60%. Then you can get to an exact number as a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facebook Question (Data Science)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335235/facebook-question-data-science)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it a bit more formally... Let $p_r$ be the prior probability for rain ($p_n=1-p_r$). Then the probability of rain given 3 "yes" replies $(y,y,y)$

$$P\{\text{rain}|y,y,y\}=\frac{P\{\text{rain}\bigcap (y,y,y)\}}{P\{y,y,y\}}$$
$$=\frac{P\{y,y,y|\text{rain}\}\cdot p_r}{P\{y,y,y|\text{rain}\}\cdot p_r+P\{y,y,y|\text{no rain}\}\cdot p_n}$$

Next, if we assume **conditional** independence of friends' replies the last formula becomes

$$=\frac{(2/3)^3\cdot p_r}{(2/3)^3\cdot p_r+(1/3)^3\cdot p_n}=\frac{p_r}{p_r+ p_n/8}$$

This answer is  duplicate from the following link
[Facebook Question (Data Science)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335235/facebook-question-data-science/1901721)

Answer (score -4):

Suppose it rains, then 3 yes answers would have been heard with probability $\frac{8}{27}$ if it does not rain, we'd hear those answers with probability $\frac{1}{27}$. We know we've heard them, so we're in one of two worlds, and one is 8 times more likely. So the intuitive answer is $\frac{8}{9}$, I'd say.

Comment: Whether "yes" is a lie is not independent of the weather.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thay are asked: is it raining? They either lie or not. 'yes" is a lie iff it is not raining.

Comment: Indeed, and to have the *same* answer then all three friends must be simultaneously telling the *same* amount of truth.  They are either all lying or all truthful.

Comment: By the Law of Total Probability, the probability that they all answer "yes" is dependent on the probability that it is raining. $$\mathsf P(Y_3) = (\tfrac 23)^3~\mathsf P(R)+(\tfrac 13)^3~(1-\mathsf P(R)) ~=~ \tfrac 1{27}(7~\mathsf P(R)+1)$$

Comment: Imagine a world where it never rains in Seattle (I'm not familiar with US climates, so as far as I'm concerned that might well be the case). Now "yes" is clearly always a lie. Yet this answer would assign a non-zero probability for rain if all three friends say "yes", so it is clearly wrong. We need to know the prior.