# probability that it is snowing

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You are about to visit Jamestown in North Dakota, to see the world's largest buffalo monument. You know that it snows $25\%$ of the time in North Dakota, and you are thinking about bringing your parka. It turns out that you have three friends who live in North Dakota, but they are not very trustworthy: Each tells the truth $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time, and lies for the remaining $\frac{1}{3}$. You call your three friends, and each friend tells you that it is indeed snowing in North Dakota. Given this information, what is the probability that it is actually snowing in North Dakota?

[Probability: is it raining?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049287/probability-is-it-raining) Is a similar question, but I'm not sure if the 25% in the 2nd setence changes anything.

Comment: If you look at the comments and the accepted answer to the question you linked to, you'll see that they all mention a "prior probability", which in that case would be the probability that it rains on a randomly selected date.  Here, the $25\%$ is your prior probability.

Comment: @lulu thanks, would p_n in this question be 1-25 = 75%?

Comment: Well, yes...$p_n=1-p_r$.  But writing things like $1-25=75\%$ is a bad habit.  Better to write $p_n=1-.25=.75$ or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facebook Question (Data Science)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335235/facebook-question-data-science)